# SQL: Decimals shown more than required

Tags: sql, select, numbers, decimal

so here is my code.

```
SELECT Concat(Round(SUM(Coalesce(Price.Morning, Price.Day, 
Price.Evening)*Tickets.count),2),' €') AS 'Total',
Concat(Round(SUM(Price.Morning * Tickets.count) * 100 / 
(SUM(Coalesce(Price.Morning, Price.Day, Price.Evening)*Tickets.count)),2),'%') 
AS 'Riti',
Concat(Round(SUM(Price.Day * Tickets.count) * 100 / 
(SUM(Coalesce(Price.Morning, Price.Day, Price.Evening)*Tickets.count)),2),'%') 
AS 'Dienas',
Concat(Round(SUM(Price.Evening * Tickets.count) * 100 / 
(SUM(Coalesce(Price.Morning, Price.Day, 
Price.Evening)*Tickets.count)),2),'%') 
AS 'Evening'
FROM Price,Tickets
WHERE Tickets.Price_ID = Price.Price_ID
;
```

And it is displayed like this:

[image]

Everything works fine but i need only 2 decimals after comma but it still display more than 2.

Comment: `round()` changes the *value*.  Cast to a `decimal()` to change the *type*.  Usually the type determines what get shown.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Don't do number formatting in SQL. Let the display layer (app, report, form etc.) do the formatting. It limits your ability to adapt to different cultures, use preferences, etc.

Just return the raw data and get rid of the formatting:

```
SELECT
    SUM(Coalesce(Price.Morning, Price.Day, Price.Evening)*Tickets.count) AS 'Total',
    SUM(Price.Morning * Tickets.count) / 
        SUM(Coalesce(Price.Morning, Price.Day, Price.Evening)*Tickets.count) AS 'Riti',
    SUM(Price.Day * Tickets.count) / 
       SUM(Coalesce(Price.Morning, Price.Day, Price.Evening)*Tickets.count) AS 'Dienas',
    SUM(Price.Evening * Tickets.count) / 
       SUM(Coalesce(Price.Morning, Price.Day, Price.Evening)*Tickets.count AS 'Evening'
FROM Price,Tickets
WHERE Tickets.Price_ID = Price.Price_ID
```

You can also simplify this a bit by putting the repeated calculation `Coalesce(Price.Morning, Price.Day, Price.Evening)*Tickets.count` in a subquery.